# Discord.js v14.7.1 - TypeError: channel.isTextBased is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I've been running a discord bot for a while now with no issues, and then all of a sudden today I began getting this error whenever users use interaction buttons. I'm not sure why it's happeneing now.

I didn't change my version of discord.js or anything like that, i'm also not using "channel.isTextBased" anywhere in my code. I'm confused as to why this has popped up all of a sudden. Any ideas?

Comment: Also seeing this today, running 14.6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems we should update to 14.8.0 which fixes the issue.

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/9295

Comment: Yup that was it, thanks!